# Calling simple jsp using sencha touch store

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to call the string inside the store. i framed the response **"Hi how are you"** in server

```
`out.print("Hi how are you");`
```

i am trying to print the response.

**Store**

```
Ext.define('PracticeSencha.store.CustomStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias : 'widget.CustomStore',
    config: {
    type: 'ajax',
        url:'sample url.jsp',
        storeId: 'productStoreID'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'text' 
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
var sto = Ext.create('PracticeSencha.store.CustomStore');
        sto.load({
            scope : this,
            callback : function(records, operation, success,failure) {
                console.log(records);
                console.log(operation);
                console.log(success);
                console.log(sto.count());
            }
        });
```

Whether we can read the normal string using Reader?

Answer (score 0):

That's possible. Create your own TextReader by extending `Ext.data.reader.Reader`. Haven't done it yet, but I guess you must override the `getResponseData`-method at least.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I feel difficult in consuming string so i changed the response to JSONP